# Polymer 1.0 access fields of the Dart objects?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following example:

**main_app.dart**

```
@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
    @property
    Tst superTst = new Tst()..field1 = "blablabla"; 
}

class Tst {
  String field1;
}
```

**main_app.html**

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
  <template>
    Teste 
    <span>{{superTst.field1}}</span> 
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

But, the `{{superTst.field1}}` does not result in text being shown!

How to access fields of the Dart objects in Polymer 1.0? (from new classes, different Map, List and primitive types)

Comment: I am using Dart Polymer 1.0 rc2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class must extend `JsProxy` and each member that should be available from Polymer needs the `@reflectable` annotation. Currently for a getter/setter pair, both need the `@reflectable` annotation (fixed already but not released AFAIK)

```
class Tst extends JsProxy {
  @reflectable String field1;
}
```

If you update the value of `field1` use

```
set('superTst.field1', 'newValue');
```

to ensure bindings are updated.

Comment: With `String field1` and `<paper-input>{{superTst.field1}}</paper-input>`, when I entry in input, works nice. But if I use `num field1` when I entry with some number, does not works! Need I just works with String type?